# How to fix error on tolowercase implementation prolog?

Tags: prolog, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a tolower implementation in prolog, but i keep getting an error and I'm not sure what it means.

```
?- tolower("HE",L).    
ERROR: tolower/2: Undefined procedure: (+)/2
```

here is my implementation so far.

```
tolower([], _).
tolower([H|T], L):-
    H + 32, tolower(T, L).
```

Answer (score 3):

Let us see what `H + 32` means:

```
?- write_canonical(H+32).
+(_,32)
```

So you are invoking a predicate called `+`, with two arguments.

You have not defined such a predicate, hence you get an error.

To evaluate **arithmetic expressions**, use for example a constraint such as `(#=)/2` for integers:

`R #= H + 32`

This is a relation, saying that `R` *is equal to* `H + 32`, evaluated as an integer expression.

Depending on your Prolog system, you may have to import a library to use `(#=)/2`.